# Scilab Error 4 Undefined variable <function_name>

Tags: function, undefined, scilab

hi ppl im new at Scilab,
im doing a script which i send the user through menus and i'm making a function for every sub-menu.
I read that functions can have 0 input parameters but it must have at least 1 output parameter.
According to this i wrote this

```
//execution file landing menu
option='1'
while (option~=0)
   clc
   mprintf('1 - First Sub-menu')
   mprintf('2 - Second Sub-menu')
   option=input('Select the option: ', 's')
   select option
   case '1' then
      result=sub_one(),
   case '2' then
      result=sub_two(),
   else
      disp('Invalid Option!!!')
   end
end

//Function sub_one
function result=sub_one()
   option='1'
   while (option~=0)
      clc
      mprintf('1 - Do stuff')
      mprintf('2 - Do other stuff')
      option=input('Select the option: ', 's')
      select option
      case '1' then
         result=do_stuff(),
      case '2' then
         result=do_other_stuff(),
      else
         disp('Invalid Option!!!')
      end
   end
   result=0
endfunction
```

and i always get the error

```
result=sub_one(),
!--error 4 
Undefined variable: sub_one
at line      xx of exec file called by :  
exec('dir\dir\dir\file.sce', -1)
```

this is freaking annoying me

some experter then me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scilab parses the file top to bottom, so when it is in your main part at the top of the file, `sub_one` does not exist yet. If you switch the order around it will work.

If you would like to retain the order in your file you can also do the following:

```
// Define some main function
function main()
    disp('hello from main')
    sub_one()
endfunction

// Define some sub function
function sub_one()
    disp('hello from sub_one')
endfunction

// call function main to execute
main()
```